# Sql two table query most duplicated foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

I got those two tables `sport` and `student`:

First table `sport`:

```
|idsport |  name      |
_______________________  
|  1     | bobsled    |  
|  2     | skating    |  
|  3     | boarding   |  
|  4     | iceskating |  
|  5     | skiing     |
```

Second table `student`:

```
                            foreign key
|idstudent |  name      |   sport_idsport
__________________________________________  
|  1       | john       |       3        |  
|  2       | pauly      |       2        |  
|  3       | max        |       1        |  
|  4       | jane       |       2        |  
|  5       | nico       |       5        |
```

so far i did this it output which number is mostly inserted, but cant get it to work
with two tables

```
SELECT  sport_idsport 
FROM (SELECT sport_idsport FROM student GROUP BY sport_idsport ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc)  
WHERE ROWNUM<=1;
```

I need to output name of most popular sport, in that case it would be skating.

I use oracle sql.

Comment: You must have tried *something*.  Please edit the question and show your efforts.

Comment: Why is the answer "skating"? "boarding" is just as popular (both are are selected two times)

Comment: my fault was in a hurry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with counter as (
    Select sport_idsport, 
           count(*) as cnt,
           dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from student 
    group by sport_idsport
)
select s.*, c.cnt
from sport s
 join counter c on c.sport_idsport = s.idsport and c.rn = 1;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b76e21/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select cnt, sport_idsport from (
  select count(*) cnt, sport_idsport
    from student
   group by sport_idsport
   order by count(*) desc
)
where rownum = 1
```